# Getting the function table from a x64 process

Tags: c++, windows, 64-bit, stack-trace

I want to walk the stack of a x64 process.
I read that in order to do so, I need to get the unwind information stored in the exe or DLL.
I've seen that there is a `RtlAddFunctionTable` but I could find any way to get this function table in the first place...
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [StackWalk64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680650%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the 64 bit version of WinDbg which ships as part of the DDK/SDK http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.

Once you attach you can then load the windows symbols:

```
.symfix;.reload;
```

You can also point it at your applications pdbs and you should be able to see full call stacks so long as your pdbs do not have the private symbols stripped from the release version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RtlLookupFunctionEntry (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/nf-winnt-rtllookupfunctionentry) to get the function table entry (struct RUNTIME_FUNCTION) associated with a particular code address.